# TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '{ depth: and Property 'response' does not exist on type '{ respnse: any; }' on Deno compile

Tags: compiler-errors, deno

This is my first time using Deno, i learn it from youtube and documentation. First thing i want to amke was make a simple local server using deno using this script.

```
Route.ts

import {Router} from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const route = new Router();

route.get('/',async({
    response
}: {
    respnse : any;
}) => {
    response.status = 200;
    response.body = {
        message: "welcome"
    }
});

export default route;
```

And this is my server.ts

```
import {Application} from  "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";
import route from './src/routes/router.ts';
const app = new Application();
const port = 3000;

app.use(route.routes());
app.use(route.allowedMethods());

console.log("server is running");

await app.listen({port})
```

I run server.ts with this command

```
C:\laragon\bin\deno>deno run D:\deno_mongo\server.ts
```

But i got this error while compile the data

```
Compile file:///D:/deno_mongo/server.ts
error: TS2769 [ERROR]: No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(name: string, path: string, ...middleware: RouterMiddleware<Record<string | number, string | undefined>, Record<string, any>>[]): Router<Record<string | number, string | undefined>, Record<...>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ response }: {    respnse: any;}) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(path: string, ...middleware: RouterMiddleware<Record<string | number, string | undefined>, Record<string, any>>[]): Router<Record<string | number, string | undefined>, Record<...>>', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '({ response }: {    respnse: any;}) => Promise<void>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'RouterMiddleware<Record<string 
| number, string | undefined>, Record<string, any>>'.
      Types of parameters '__0' and 'context' are incompatible.
        Property 'respnse' is missing in type 'RouterContext<Record<string | number, string | undefined>, Record<string, any>>' but required in type '{ respnse: any; }'.
route.get('/',async({

    at file:///D:/deno_mongo/src/routes/router.ts:5:15

    'respnse' is declared here.
        respnse : any;
        ~~~~~~~
        at file:///D:/deno_mongo/src/routes/router.ts:8:5

TS2339 [ERROR]: Property 'response' does not exist on type '{ respnse: any; }'.
    response
    ~~~~~~~~
    at file:///D:/deno_mongo/src/routes/router.ts:6:5

TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '{ depth: number; sorted: boolean; trailingComma: boolean; compact: boolean; iterableLimit: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InspectOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sorted' does not exist in type 'InspectOptions'.
        sorted: true,
        ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    at https://deno.land/std@0.61.0/testing/asserts.ts:26:9

Found 3 errors.
```

Here is my deno version.

```
deno 1.0.3
v8 8.4.300
typescript 3.9.2
```

How to solve this error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Gagantous: I took happened to witness the same issue. I was running with deno 1.1.1 version, but in https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6780, issue track it has been mentioned like we need to upgrade to deno 1.2.0. I did the force upgrade to make the fix. After that it is working fine.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo: `respnse : any;` => `response: any;`

Instead of `any` you can use `Response` instead which is the actual type.

```
import { Router, Response } from "https://deno.land/x/oak/mod.ts";

const route = new Router();

route.get('/',async({
    response
}: {
    response : Response; // Error here

}) => {
    response.status = 200;
    response.body = {
        message: "welcome"
    }
});

export default route;
```

Comment: i tried this but i got this error `TS2345 [ERROR]: Argument of type '{ depth: number; sorted: boolean; trailingComma: boolean; compact: boolean; iterableLimit: number; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'InspectOptions'.
  Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'sorted' does not exist in type 'InspectOptions'.`

Comment: On what file, what line? I can run your snippet perfectly with my changes.

Comment: when run this C:\laragon\bin\deno>deno run D:\deno_mongo\server.ts, it gives me an error message

Comment: On what file and what line. Show the complete stack trace. And again it's not happening with the code you posted here.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced the same problem and i resolved it by upgrading the version of deno that installed on my machine my old version was `1.1.2` after upgrading version to latest one `1.2.0` this issue resolved and it's working fine now

Just take a look about this issue [deno](https://github.com/denoland/deno/issues/6780)